# How to get the reference to the instance variable?

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following code to get the value of my class instance variable.

```
public void printFields(Object obj) throws Exception {
    Class<?> objClass = obj.getClass();

    Field[] fields = objClass.getFields();
    for(Field field : fields) {
        String name = field.getName();
        Object value = field.get(obj);

        System.out.println(name + ": " + value.toString());
    }
}
```

Lets say for class `A`, which has type `ArrayList`. Looks like:

```
class A
{
   private ArrayList list;
}
```

Now I want to get the reference to this type `list`. Is it possible?

So that once I get the reference all the methods available in the `ArrayList` should be accessible.

How to do it?

Comment: It is possible, but why you want to violate encapsulation?

Comment: No I need to generate map of my class variables. So basically from the text file, I get the instance variable name. I need to iterate my class and get its instance variable reference, so that I can use it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `field.setAccessible(true);` to circumvent encapsulation. This doesn't necessarily always work: a `SecurityException` may be thrown.

It's far better (if you *own* the class), to set the member `public` and be done with it:

```
class A
{
   public ArrayList list;
}
```

At least then your usage pattern is *expected*.

Once you have obtained the `list` then any public methods and fields on that list will be available to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value from the `Field` instance by:

1. Setting the field as *accessible* with [AccessibleObject#setAccessible(boolean b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) method (which is implemented in the `Field` class).
2. Fetching its value via the [Field#get(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

For example:

```
for (Field f : fields) {
    f.setAccessible(true);
    ArrayList value = (ArrayList) f.get(objClass);
}
```

Comment: its getting the value. not the reference I guess. What happens if the `list` (in my case) is null that time, but in fact has proxys set?

Comment: It gets a copied reference, I think

Comment: Cant get the actual reference?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public ArrayList getField(A obj) throws Exception{
    Class c = obj.getClass();
    Field f = c.getDeclaredField("list");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    ArrayList lst = (ArrayList)f.get(obj);
    return lst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to get all fields declared in instance class (not only public ones) you need to use `getDeclaredFields()` instead of `getFields()`.
2. Also if you want to have access to value of private fields you need to set its accessibility to `true` with `field.setAccessible(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. For non public fields you must use the field.getDeclaredField() method.
If you wish to set or read a value for that field, you must use field.setAccessible(true).
Be careful for NPE when using value.toString() for null fields.

```
public static void printFields(Object obj) throws Exception {
    Class<?> objClass = obj.getClass();

    Field[] fields = objClass.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field : fields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        String name = field.getName();
        Object value = field.get(obj);

        System.out.println(name + ": " + value);
    }
}
```